# Staubli TX2-140 URDF

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

Where coul I find the URDF for Staubli TX2-140? I want to insert it in ROS and Gazebo and also use Peter Corke python toolbox to model it? How can I implement it in the toolbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only ROS support I am aware of was for the Staubli CS8C with a RX160 robot arm. The TX2-140 runs on a CS9 controller. I am not aware of any ROS support for the TX2-140 arm or the CS9 controller. Staubli has never officially support ROS or Gazebo.